# How do I order this list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
[(u'we', 'PRP'), (u'saw', 'VBD'), (u'you', 'PRP'), (u'bruh', 'VBP'), (u'.', '.')]
```

I want to order this alphabetically, by "PRP, VBD, PRP, and VBP"
It's not the traditional sort, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use itemgetter:

```
>>> a = [(u'we', 'PRP'), (u'saw', 'VBD'), (u'you', 'PRP'), (u'bruh', 'VBP'), (u'.', '.')]
>>> import operator
>>> a.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> a
[(u'.', '.'), (u'we', 'PRP'), (u'you', 'PRP'), (u'saw', 'VBD'), (u'bruh', 'VBP')]
```

Comment: Acceptable solution ... but I don't think it's worth an import. :) I prefer Dave Webb's way.

Answer (score 7):

The [`sort` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) takes a `key` argument to extract a comparison key from each argument, i.e. `key` is a function which transforms the list item into the value you wish to sort on.

In this case it's very easy to [use a `lambda`](http://www.diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) to extract the second item from each tuple:

```
>>> mylist = [(u'we', 'PRP'), (u'saw', 'VBD'), (u'you', 'PRP'), (u'bruh', 'VBP')
, (u'.', '.')]
>>> mylist.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
>>> mylist
[(u'.', '.'), (u'we', 'PRP'), (u'you', 'PRP'), (u'saw', 'VBD'), (u'bruh', 'VBP')]
```

Comment: Actualy, it is the same as itemgetter but at least you see what's it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a comparison function in the `sort` method.

Example:

```
l = [(u'we', 'PRP'), (u'saw', 'VBD'), (u'you', 'PRP'), (u'bruh', 'VBP'), (u'.', '.')]
l.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x[1], y[1])) # compare tuple's 2nd elements
```

Output:

```
>>> l
[(u'.', '.'),
 (u'we', 'PRP'),
 (u'you', 'PRP'),
 (u'saw', 'VBD'),
 (u'bruh', 'VBP')]
>>>
```

Comment: Using a key with sort is preferable to using cmp, as the key only gets called N times where cmp will be called NlogN times. You have no choice in python3, support for cmp has been removed

Comment: @gnibbler, thanks for the tip. Why the key will be called only N times? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Nick, because with `key` Python will go through the list once to calculate the keys, then sort using those keys. With `cmp`, on the other hand, it will call the function every time it needs to compare two values.

Comment: hmm, so it collects the keys prior sorting. Thanks. But won't this step use extra memory? Is it really faster than using the `cmp`, for large lists? I have to test the 2 approaches ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or use the Built-in Function sorted (similar to Nick_D's answer):

```
ls = [(u'we', 'PRP'), (u'saw', 'VBD'), (u'you', 'PRP'), (u'bruh', 'VBP'), (u'.', '.')]


sorted(ls, cmp=lambda t1, t2: cmp(t1[1], t2[1]))
```